# Petición errónea en api

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks

Estoy utilizando React (soy principiante), estoy realizando una petición a una `API`, básicamente estoy haciendo una búsqueda de un producto por el nombre, pero el problema esta en que quiero mostrar texto `html` cuando el usuario escriba algo que no se encuentre en la `API`, he intentado realizando condiciones y nada, hice una prueba escribiendo cualquier cosa y este me retorna un `array` vacío. El código es el siguiente:

```
const Business = () => {

    const [info, setInfo] = useState([]);
    const [query, setQuery] = useState('chicken');

    /* searh component */
    const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");

    const exampleReq = `direccion del api`;
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getRecepies();
    }, [query]);

    const getRecepies = async() =>{
        const response = await fetch(exampleReq);
        const data = await response.json();
        setInfo(data.hits);
    }

    const getSearch = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setQuery(inputText)
    }
    return (
        <>
            <Header />
            <div class="container-workers">
                <Search
                    setInputText={setInputText}
                    getSearch={getSearch}
                />
                <div class="each-worker">
                    {info.map(infos =>(
                        <CardBusiness
                            key={infos.recipe.label}
                            title={infos.recipe.label}
                            img={infos.recipe.image}
                        />
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Estoy consumiendo una api de una pagina web. De antemano gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede utilizar un [operador ternario](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

En React, se puede usar así:

```
{ info == "" ? (
        <p>Texto a mostrar si no hay resultados de la API</p>
    ) : (
        info.map(infos =>(
            <CardBusiness
                key={infos.recipe.label}
                title={infos.recipe.label}
                img={infos.recipe.image}
            />
        ))
    )
 }
```

Ahí, si el estado `info` es igual a un vacío `""`, se muestra el texto con los  `<p></p>` informando que no hubo resultados. Pero si la API sí trajo resultados, le hace el `.map` al array con su contenido.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda. pero no me muestra nada en pantalla, no se si las comillas influyen en la condicional, pero de todos modos la cambie y pues igual no sale nada

Comment: Es verdad, no está bien que sean las llaves entre comillas. La manera correcta es validar si `info` es igual a `""`, es decir, si `info` está vacío. Porque el array vacío se interpreta como esas dobles comillas, o sea que no tiene contenido. Ya lo edité en mi respuesta. Vuélvelo a intentar así, y esta vez debería funcionar.

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda, ya funcionó

Comment: Genial. No olvides de marcar una respuesta como "aceptada" si realmente te fue útil, [aquí se explica cómo hacerlo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas). Al acostumbrarte a hacer eso con todas tus preguntas resueltas, ayudarás a identificar más rápidamente las soluciones que funcionan a todas las otras personas que tengan tu mismo problema.

Comment: solo una consulta, si la petición devuelve un array vacío "[]" la condición no tendría que ser con [], pero no me funciona con eso, en cambio me funciona con "".

Comment: El problema principal de porqué no funcionaba es que al comparar dos arrays vacíos nos da `false`. La explicación de porqué eso es así es algo compleja, pero si quieres investigarlo más a fondo encontré una pregunta en inglés en donde lo responden: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703222/why-is-false-in-javascript.  Pero en este caso bastaba con comparar el array vacío con el  `""`, ya que ambas expresiones no tienen contenido y esa comparación sí da `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar lo siguiente para validar si la respuesta `info` tiene algún contenido y si no puedes mostrar un texto indicándolo.

```
      {info.length ? (
        info.map((infos) => (
          <CardBusiness
            key={infos.recipe.label}
            title={infos.recipe.label}
            img={infos.recipe.image}
          />
        ))
      ) : (
        <p>No recipes found!</p>
      )}
```

Comment: Es otra opción válida, y también harías buen uso del operador ternario.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, también me funciona de esta manera.